# How to join values of one object?

Tags: javascript

Get values and join with `','`

```
const users = [{
  name: "Jon",
  age: 34,
  country: "ES"
}]

users.map(function(a){
   for (let item in a) { 
     console.log(a[item])
  }
})

//users.join(", ");
```

I want to return `Jon,34,ES`.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Object.values and map: Objet.values returns an array of values in the object and join converts these values to string by joining them by ',' here.

```js
const users = [{
  name: "Jon",
  age: 34,
  country: "ES"
}];

var result = users.map(u => Object.values(u).join(','));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The `','` in your `join` is not needed because that's the default value.

Comment: @Werner Thank you for the remark. I just keep the ',' to make things clear

Answer (score 5):

You can use *Object.values* to get an array of the properties of your object, then use the *join* method of that array to create a string from the values:

```
var result = users.map(function (a) {
    return Object.values(a).join(', ');
});
console.log(result[0]); // Jon, 34, ES
```

Answer (score 4):

You can map your users array and join the values of each user dictionary.

```
users.map(user => Object.values(user).join(', '));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const users = [{
  name: "Jon",
  age: 34,
  country: "ES"
},{
  name: "Sam",
  age: 24,
  country: "US"
}]

let arrayOfStrings = users.map(function(a){
     return Object.values(a).join(',')
  }
})
// arrayOfStrings = ["Jon,34,ES", "Sam,24,US"]

//ES6 way:
let arrayOfStrings = users.map( a => Object.values(a).join(',') )
// arrayOfStrings = ["Jon,34,ES", "Sam,24,US"]
```

**arrayOfStrings** will contains an array of strings made from objects.

For reference of the methods used:

1. [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
2. [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

Because there are already a bunch of solutions which work, I want to provide a different one.

Like your one:

```js
const users = [{
  name: "Jon",
  age: 34,
  country: "ES"
}]

const results = users.map(function(a) {
  const values = [];
  for (let item in a) {
    values.push(a[item]);
  }
  return values.join(", ");
})

console.log(results);
```

Or for really old browser support (IE6+), like this:

```js
var users = [{
  name: "Jon",
  age: 34,
  country: "ES"
}]

var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var values = [];
  for (let x in users[i]) {
    values.push(users[i][x]);
  }
  results.push(values.join(", "));
}

console.log(results);
```

Anyway, I'd prefer a modern solution using [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) like others in this thread used.